# WSGI, application, вызов функции

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть функция application, в которой нужно вызвать другую функцию hdf2(hdf1), при выполнении кода, hdf2(hdf1) не вызывается и при этом 500-я ошибка.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
try:
    if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/':
        status = '200 OK'
        f = open(r'./template/base.html')
        output = f.read()
        f.close()
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'html'), #('charset', 'utf-8'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [output]

    elif environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/map':

        if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
            fields = request.parse_formvars(environ)
            map = fields.get('map', 'default')
            prod = fields.get('prod', 'default')
            hdf1 = ['test1', 'test2']
            hdf2(hdf1)
        status = '200 OK'
        f = open(r'./template/test.html')
        output = f.read()
        f.close()

        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'html; charset=UTF-8'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [output % (prod, map)]
except:
    status = "500 Error"
    response_headers = [("content-type", "text/plain")]
    start_response(status, response_headers, sys.exc_info())
    return ["Error"]
```

В чём может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо! Пробовал вот так return [hdf2(hdf1), output % (prod, map)]

Comment: А вы не пробовали посмотреть, почему ошибка происходит? Т.е. какое сообщение об ошибке в блоке except?

По коду:

    fields = request.parse_formvars(environ)

а где у вас request объявлен?

Comment: В самом начале программы.




import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi
from paste import request

Comment: Я разобрался, дело было в том, что используется  в программе Celery из-за неправильной конфигурации которой и была ошибка.